# What are "model variables" in Tensorflow and slim?

Tags: tensorflow

From https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim,

> TF-Slim further differentiates variables by defining model variables,
>   which are variables that represent parameters of a model. Model
>   variables are trained or fine-tuned during learning and are loaded
>   from a checkpoint during evaluation or inference. Examples include the
>   variables created by a slim.fully_connected or slim.conv2d layer.
>   Non-model variables are all other variables that are used during
>   learning or evaluation but are not required for actually performing
>   inference. For example, the global_step is a variable using during
>   learning and evaluation but it is not actually part of the model.
>   Similarly, moving average variables might mirror model variables, but
>   the moving averages are not themselves model variables.

From https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops/variable_helper_functions,

> tf.model_variables()
>
> Returns all variables in the MODEL_VARIABLES collection.

Yet slim creates "moving mean" variables as part of its batch norm layers that are included in the MODEL_VARIABLES collection.

I can see at least possible definitions of "model variable":

1. Used in inference.
2. Fine tuned during training (whether by an optimizer or some other means such as moving averaging).
3. Stored in checkpoints

Is it the case that Tensorflow's "model variables" are defined by condition 2, while slim's "model variables" are defined by condition 1?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, slim uses contrib layers. contrib layers use layer_variable_getter, which is actually _model_variable_getter, to generate "model_variable" that are variables added into [tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, tf.GraphKeys.MODEL_VARIABLES] collections.

Therefore model variables are common variables plus being added to MODEL_VARIABLES collection. contrib layers' variables are model variables plus being renamed from 'bias' to 'biases' and from 'kernel' to 'weights' if needed.