# Difference between get_variable and model_variable function?

Tags: variables, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, difference

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37102908/3552975) I got to know the difference between the `Variable` and the `get_variable` but I encounter one more method to get or create a variable that is [model_variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/model_variable), then I am confused when to use `get_variable` and when to choose `model_variable`.

For the documentations I know that:

get_variable:

> Gets an existing variable with these parameters or create a new one.

model_variable:

> Gets an existing model variable with these parameters or creates a new one.

I can see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41456454/3552975) that:

> Returns all variables in the MODEL_VARIABLES collection.

Then is it true that the only difference between get_variable and model_variable function lies on the collection they are longing to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, yes. Looking at the source code for `model_variable` on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py), `model_variable` wraps `variable` (defined in the linked module), which itself is a wrapper for `get_variable`.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456454/what-are-model-variables-in-tensorflow-and-slim) seems to confirm that, and this Google Groups [discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/PV9tOwxoeiU) gives insight into why `tf.contrib` has seemingly duplicate functions, and specifically this function.

As for which one to use, probably always `tf.get_variable` unless you are integrating something with slim or something else that specifically calls for it. I've never used `model_variable` myself.

EDIT: Clarify that `variable` is defined in the link, not `tf.Variable`.

Comment: Oh, get_variable seems to be the wrapper for Variable,,,,,

Comment: Technically true. `tf.Variable` is the *class* for any, well, variable in the graph. As variable scoping became more important, mainly to reuse variables AFAIK, `tf.get_variable` was written to abstract away variable scope handling. `tf.get_variable` is preferred now, even though official examples still use `tf.Variable` (same story with `tf.variable_scope` and `tf.name_scope`). .... I'm sure `tf.GraphKeys.MODEL_VARIABLES` abstracts something away in the context of Slim and contrib.layers, but in core TensorFlow I don't know of any purpose. @lerner